# cd command - why giving it an integer goes to home directory

Tags: bash, macos

I have just discovered that my OSX bash behaves like this when I type

```
$ cd code/hack/foo/
$ ls # empty directory
$ cd 0
$ pwd
/Users/hrvoje
$ cd -
$ pwd
/code/hack/foo
$ cd 123
$ pwd
/Users/hrvoje
```

My question is - why does `cd 0` or `cd 123` change directory to `$HOME` instead of displaying an error about a missing directory?

EDIT: Here is an output of `set -x` after running `cd 123` with altered `PS4`.

```
::::+[[ exec_scmb_expand_args builtin cd 0 != '' ]]
::::+chruby_auto
::auto.sh:chruby_auto:44+local dir=/Users/hrvoje/code/hack/foo/ version
::auto.sh:chruby_auto:44+[[ -z /Users/hrvoje/code/hack/foo/ ]]
::auto.sh:chruby_auto:44+dir=/Users/hrvoje/code/hack/foo
::auto.sh:chruby_auto:44+[[ -n '' ]]
::auto.sh:chruby_auto:44+[[ -z /Users/hrvoje/code/hack/foo ]]
::auto.sh:chruby_auto:44+dir=/Users/hrvoje/code/hack
::auto.sh:chruby_auto:44+[[ -n '' ]]
::auto.sh:chruby_auto:44+[[ -z /Users/hrvoje/code/hack ]]
::auto.sh:chruby_auto:44+dir=/Users/hrvoje/code
::auto.sh:chruby_auto:44+[[ -n '' ]]
::auto.sh:chruby_auto:44+[[ -z /Users/hrvoje/code ]]
::auto.sh:chruby_auto:44+dir=/Users/hrvoje
::auto.sh:chruby_auto:44+[[ -n '' ]]
::auto.sh:chruby_auto:44+[[ -z /Users/hrvoje ]]
::auto.sh:chruby_auto:44+dir=/Users
::auto.sh:chruby_auto:44+[[ -n '' ]]
::auto.sh:chruby_auto:44+[[ -z /Users ]]
::auto.sh:chruby_auto:44+dir=
::auto.sh:chruby_auto:44+[[ -n '' ]]
::auto.sh:chruby_auto:44+[[ -z '' ]]
::auto.sh:chruby_auto:44+[[ -n '' ]]
:::+exec_scmb_expand_args builtin cd 0
::status_shortcuts.sh:exec_scmb_expand_args:44+scmb_expand_args builtin cd 0
::status_shortcuts.sh:scmb_expand_args:0+'[' builtin = --relative ']'
::status_shortcuts.sh:exec_scmb_expand_args:44+sed -e 's/\([][|;()<>^ "'\''&]\)/\\\1/g'
::status_shortcuts.sh:scmb_expand_args:0+first=1
::status_shortcuts.sh:scmb_expand_args:0+OLDIFS='
'
::status_shortcuts.sh:scmb_expand_args:0+IFS=' '
::status_shortcuts.sh:scmb_expand_args:0+for arg in "$@"
::status_shortcuts.sh:scmb_expand_args:0+[[ builtin =~ ^[0-9]{0,4}$ ]]
::status_shortcuts.sh:scmb_expand_args:0+[[ builtin =~ ^[0-9]+-[0-9]+$ ]]
::status_shortcuts.sh:scmb_expand_args:0+'[' 1 -eq 1 ']'
::status_shortcuts.sh:scmb_expand_args:0+first=0
::status_shortcuts.sh:scmb_expand_args:0+printf %s builtin
::status_shortcuts.sh:scmb_expand_args:0+for arg in "$@"
::status_shortcuts.sh:scmb_expand_args:0+[[ cd =~ ^[0-9]{0,4}$ ]]
::status_shortcuts.sh:scmb_expand_args:0+[[ cd =~ ^[0-9]+-[0-9]+$ ]]
::status_shortcuts.sh:scmb_expand_args:0+'[' 0 -eq 1 ']'
::status_shortcuts.sh:scmb_expand_args:0+printf '\t'
::status_shortcuts.sh:scmb_expand_args:0+printf %s cd
::status_shortcuts.sh:scmb_expand_args:0+for arg in "$@"
::status_shortcuts.sh:scmb_expand_args:0+[[ 0 =~ ^[0-9]{0,4}$ ]]
::status_shortcuts.sh:scmb_expand_args:0+'[' 0 -eq 1 ']'
::status_shortcuts.sh:scmb_expand_args:0+printf '\t'
::status_shortcuts.sh:scmb_expand_args:0+'[' -e 0 ']'
::status_shortcuts.sh:scmb_expand_args:0+_print_path '' e0
::status_shortcuts.sh:_print_path:16+'[' '' = 1 ']'
::status_shortcuts.sh:_print_path:16+eval printf %s '"$e0"'
:::status_shortcuts.sh:_print_path:16+printf %s ''
::status_shortcuts.sh:scmb_expand_args:0+IFS='
'
:status_shortcuts.sh:exec_scmb_expand_args:44+eval 'builtin cd  '
::status_shortcuts.sh:exec_scmb_expand_args:44+builtin cd
::::+is_on_git
::.sexy_prompt:is_on_git:1+git rev-parse
::::+parse_git_branch
::repo_index.sh:parse_git_branch:1+/usr/local/bin/git branch --no-color
::repo_index.sh:parse_git_branch:1+sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/\1/'
```

Comment: Run `set -x` before `cd 123` -- what does it say it's executing? That is to say, does the shell think it's running `cd 123`, or does it think it's running `cd` with no arguments, or is it actually invoking a shell function or alias?

Comment: If it's running a function and you want to figure out where that function was defined, in addition to the `set -x`, also run `PS4=':${BASH_SOURCE##*/}:${FUNCNAME}:${BASH_LINENO}+'` to log the filename, function name, and line number for each command executed.

Comment: ...but to be very, very clear: bash on MacOS does not have the behavior you describe here out-of-the-box. Something on your system was customized to cause this to happen, and we need to track down what that customization was to be able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Interesting... Edited my question with output from `set -x`.

Comment: Set the `PS4` I suggested and regenerate those logs, please.

Comment: BTW, on a quick code read, `scm_breeze` appears to have some bugs that could be used by someone malicious to make code embedded in a directory name be executed. I strongly advise against its use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've installed a tool called `scm_breeze`, which customizes how your shell behaves.

This tool supports "numbered shortcuts", and is trying to expand your value as such; the relevant code is [here](https://github.com/scmbreeze/scm_breeze/blob/a59ace0f297402031d3a47b1b59f9bf8c776a822/lib/git/status_shortcuts.sh#L128).

Since there is no shortcut `0` defined (which is to say, no variable named `e0`), the result is an empty value -- and `cd` with no arguments changes to the home directory.